# Ai to Png Using PHP

Tags: php, adobe, adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to convert AI to PNG using PHP?

Comment: You can run Image Ready in PHP.

Comment: It depends on the version of Adobe Illustrator format that the AI file is in, but some of them can be saved in PDF compatible formats, so that might help.

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) supports conversing from AI to JPG

Comment: Not according to the list http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php ; however it may support AI files saved in PDF compatible formats from versions 10 and up. But then only with Ghostscript.

Comment: Hm, I thought I read that it did, it treated them as vector files. Maybe people were talking about PDF compatible Ai files from Illustrator CS as you said...

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure that GhostView can convert from AI to PNG with the command line interface of ghostview.

The AI-format is just a more organized and stricter version of PostScript, e.g. loop-constructs and other high-level control-flow constructs of the PostScript language are not used.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard that this can be done. 
Most known image processing libraries are [ImageMagick](http://es2.php.net/imagick) and [GD](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), but I really doubt any can raster a proprietary format as AI.